# Change icons associated with phone, mobile, and email in moderncv

Tags: moderncv

How can I change moderncv package to give me icons for the `\phone \mobile \email` commands? Currently, it prints H for mobile, T for phone, and B for email which doesn't make any sense. I've seen examples where they have small pictures instead, but I can not tell what the difference between the source for those files and mine is.

What I have: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/287148/template.pdf

What I want: http://ctan.mirrorcatalogs.com/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples/template.pdf

My code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[red]{classic}         

\title{your Curriculum Vitae title}
\firstname{Name}
\familyname{Lastname}
\mobile{Mobile}
\phone{Phone}
\email{Email}
\homepage{Homepage}
\extrainfo{Extra Info}
\photo[64pt]{picture}
\quote{Subtitle}
\address{Address}{City, Country}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Section Name}
\cvline{Subject}{Description.}
\cventry{Time}{Position}{Company Name}{City}{Country}{Description}
\cvcomputer{Skill}{Description}{Skill}{Description}
\cvlanguage{Language}{Proficiency}{Description} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your posted code produces this:

[image]

Check your log file, it appears that you do not have the marvosym fonts installed.

Comment: You were right. It appears I had two warnings from not having marvosym installed. However, I just installed marvosym and the warnings are gone but the output is the same. EDIT: It hasn't changed because installing that package has caused building the pdf to fail. One moment.

Comment: That would indicate a faulty font installation (eg installing the tfm so TeX is happy but not the actual fonts. Hard to say.) did you manually install or run a miktex or texlive package manager?

Comment: I installed from the MikTeX package manager. It says `!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file umvs): Font umvs at 864 not found`

Comment: Solved: Had to run:
`initexmf.exe --mkmaps` and 
`initexmf.exe --update-fndb`