# Removing Symbols from moderncv Document

Tags: symbols, moderncv

I'm enjoying the `moderncv` class for creating sharp looking cover letters and CVs. But, I'd like to remove the symbols associated with phone, email, etc. Is this possible?

Comment: Does this help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96557/34618

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `moderncv` class defines a command for each of these symbols. You can redefine them to do nothing (after loading any `moderncvtheme`).

```
\renewcommand*{\addresssymbol}       {}
\renewcommand*{\mobilephonesymbol}   {}
\renewcommand*{\fixedphonesymbol}    {}
\renewcommand*{\faxphonesymbol}      {}
\renewcommand*{\emailsymbol}         {}
\renewcommand*{\homepagesymbol}      {}
\renewcommand*{\linkedinsocialsymbol}{}
\renewcommand*{\twittersocialsymbol} {}
\renewcommand*{\githubsocialsymbol}  {}
```

Comment: Alan, thanks for your help. This worked perfectly.

Comment: Now how to remove the additional dots between the removed entries? ;)

Comment: @Megachip If you're having problems with this answer, perhaps you could ask a new question with a link to this question and  with a minimal working example that shows the problem.  In a basic `moderncv` document there are no 'dots' that I can see.

Comment: Additional: to get rid of the bullet points between the phone/mail elements (@Megachip): \renewcommand*{\footsymbol} {~}