# Bullet points in moderncv

Tags: moderncv

I wonder how to remove the bullet points in the moderncv footer between, e.g. mobile phone and email. I originally asked at

[Removing Symbols from moderncv Document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140771/removing-symbols-from-moderncv-document/217796#217796)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are more precise (but complex) ways to achieve this but the simplest is re-defining the `\footersymbol`

```
\renewcommand*{\footersymbol}{\qquad}
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{green}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\name{Some}{John Doe}
\title{Resume title}
\address{Dirección}{CP, Ciudad}{País}%
\phone[mobile]{000-000-000-000}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{mailmailmail@gmail.com}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}

\renewcommand*{\footersymbol}{\qquad}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That almost does the trick. Bullet points are gone. However, the space between phone and email is as if the bullet points were still there.

Comment: @Felix Because I have inserted `\renewcommand*{\footersymbol}{\qquad}`. If you don't want space, use `\renewcommand*{\footersymbol}{\space}` or even `\renewcommand*{\footersymbol}{}`

Comment: With `\moderncvstyle{banking}` you need to use `\renewcommand*{\maketitlesymbol}{\qquad}` instead (which is a more sensible name; `\maketitledelimiter` will be even better…).

Comment: @JúdaRonén true, but question was about `casual` style.

Comment: not work anymore

Comment: @PeterEbelsberger: `modercv` has changed a lot. I feel it would be better to ask a new question. You may link this question to new question.

Answer (score 2):

As for the `casual` style, the command `\footersymbol` was renamed to `\footsymbol`, see `moderncvfooti.sty` (line 29).

In other words, the code:

```
\renewcommand*{\footsymbol}{\qquad}
```

now does the job.

Just for completeness, my `TeX` distribution provides `moderncv` v2.0.0.

P.s. Haven't got enough reputation to simply comment below Harish's answer, which just needs to be updated.