# Old and nice moderncv template does not work any more

Tags: moderncv

The solution of question [Bullet points in moderncv](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217893/bullet-points-in-moderncv/217895?noredirect=1#comment729333_217895) does not work any more but it seems to be nice to be used in the future.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{green}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\name{Some}{John Doe}
\title{Resume title}
\address{Dirección}{CP, Ciudad}{País}%
\phone[mobile]{000-000-000-000}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{mailmailmail@gmail.com}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}

\renewcommand*{\footersymbol}{\qquad}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

I am no able to compile this piece of code.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there's still no manual for `moderncv`, so I took a look at the source codes.

To remove the bullet points change `footersymbol` to `footsymbol`. The code below should compile now:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{green}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\name{Some}{John Doe}
\title{Resume title}
\address{Dirección}{CP, Ciudad}{País}%
\phone[mobile]{000-000-000-000}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{mailmailmail@gmail.com}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\extrainfo{additional information}
%\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}

\renewcommand*{\footsymbol}{\qquad} %change from 'footersymbol' to 'footsymbol'
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```