# Delete or remove symbols

Tags: formatting, symbols, moderncv

I have one questions regarding `moderncv`. [here](https://github.com/dloman/latex-moderncv/blob/master/coverletter.tex)

The first one: I could not figure out how to remove the symbols from `moderncv`. I tried the linked answer and past into the `moderncv.cls` and nothing changed it.

[Removing Symbols from moderncv Document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140771/removing-symbols-from-moderncv-document)

I tried this:

```
\renewcommand*{\addresssymbol}       {}
\renewcommand*{\mobilephonesymbol}   {}
\renewcommand*{\fixedphonesymbol}    {}
\renewcommand*{\faxphonesymbol}      {}
\renewcommand*{\emailsymbol}         {}
\renewcommand*{\homepagesymbol}      {}
\renewcommand*{\linkedinsocialsymbol}{}
\renewcommand*{\twittersocialsymbol} {}
\renewcommand*{\githubsocialsymbol}  {}
```

I would appreciate any help
Some code in the main.

```
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}          
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
```

I am working with

```
%% start of file `template.tex'.
%% Copyright 2006-2013 Xavier Danaux (xdanaux@gmail.com).
%% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License version 1.3c,
% available at http://www.latex-project.org/lppl/.


\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
```

Comment: First of all: You should not change the `.cls` file... Second: Provide a compilable document and specify, which symbols should be removed...

Comment: What's the problem with thoses symbols? Why removing them ?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer How can I share this document. I will add the free source for this cover letter.

Comment: @Mayra: You can edit your question and paste the code

Comment: @PTRK it is not used in my country.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I do not know in which document of the files I should change because there are many subfiles such as main, cls, and others pre default

Comment: Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` instead of code snippets. Otherwise we have no way of testing _anything_.

Comment: You are working with a template you downloaded, correct? Please give the top part of main.tex

Comment: I noticed the link later. Actually, that part is misleading and not helpful at all. But this is the fault of the owner of that GitHub repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need not to change the class file, simply add the `\renewcommands` in your letter code.

Please note that the current version of class `moderncv` is 2.0.0. The github repository you linked to uses an outdated version! Better use the current one!

With the following MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic} % casual, classic, banking, oldstyle and fancy
\moderncvcolor{blue} 

\renewcommand*{\addresssymbol}       {} % <=============================
\renewcommand*{\mobilephonesymbol}   {}
\renewcommand*{\fixedphonesymbol}    {}
\renewcommand*{\faxphonesymbol}      {}
\renewcommand*{\emailsymbol}         {}
\renewcommand*{\homepagesymbol}      {}
\renewcommand*{\linkedinsocialsymbol}{}
\renewcommand*{\twittersocialsymbol} {}
\renewcommand*{\githubsocialsymbol}  {} % <=============================

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-a}
\quote{Some quote}

\setlength{\footskip}{66pt}


\begin{document}

%-----       letter       ---------------------------------------------------------
% recipient data
\recipient{Company Recruitment team}{Company, Inc.\\123 somestreet\\some city}
\date{January 01, 1984}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,}
\closing{Yours faithfully,}
\enclosure[Attached]{curriculum vit\ae{}}
\makelettertitle

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ullamcorper 
neque sit amet lectus facilisis sed luctus nisl iaculis. Vivamus at neque 
arcu, sed tempor quam. Curabitur pharetra tincidunt tincidunt. Morbi 
volutpat feugiat mauris, quis tempor neque vehicula volutpat. Duis 
tristique justo vel massa fermentum accumsan. Mauris ante elit, feugiat 
vestibulum tempor eget, eleifend ac ipsum. Donec scelerisque lobortis 
ipsum eu vestibulum. Pellentesque vel massa at felis accumsan rhoncus.

Suspendisse commodo, massa eu congue tincidunt, elit mauris pellentesque 
orci, cursus tempor odio nisl euismod augue. Aliquam adipiscing nibh ut 
odio sodales et pulvinar tortor laoreet. Mauris a accumsan ligula. 
Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per 
inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse vulputate sem vehicula ipsum varius nec 
tempus dui dapibus. Phasellus et est urna, ut auctor erat. Sed tincidunt 
odio id odio aliquam mattis. Donec sapien nulla, feugiat eget adipiscing 
sit amet, lacinia ut dolor. Phasellus tincidunt, leo a fringilla 
consectetur, felis diam aliquam urna, vitae aliquet lectus orci nec 
velit. Vivamus dapibus varius blandit.

Duis sit amet magna ante, at sodales diam. Aenean consectetur porta risus 
et sagittis. Ut interdum, enim varius pellentesque tincidunt, magna 
libero sodales tortor, ut fermentum nunc metus a ante. Vivamus odio leo, 
tincidunt eu luctus ut, sollicitudin sit amet metus. Nunc sed orci 
lectus. Ut sodales magna sed velit volutpat sit amet pulvinar diam 
venenatis.

Albert Einstein discovered that $e=mc^2$ in 1905.

\[ e=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \]

\makeletterclosing

\end{document}
```

you get the (wished?) result:

[image]