# moderncv banking

Tags: moderncv

I have the following problem on the moderncv-class:
[image]

As you can see all personal information is perfect to an imaginary line to the right except for "city" which obviously is somewhat to the left. Of course I'd like to have all lines ending at the perfectly at the imaginary line at the right.

Further, I'd like to have more modern symbols for the mobile, mail etc. I know that there is a way to change them, but unfortunately I don't know how...

Here I have a MWE:

```
   \RequirePackage[demo]{graphicx}
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}   

\moderncvtheme[black]{banking}



\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter


\newcommand*{\birthdate}[1]{\def\@birthdate{#1}}
\newcommand*{\civilstatus}[1]{\def\@civilstatus{#1}}

\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{34}{36}\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\titlefont}{\LARGE\mdseries\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\addressfont}{\small\mdseries\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\quotefont}{\large\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\sectionfont}{\Large\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionfont}{\large\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\hintfont}{}

% styles
\renewcommand*{\namestyle}[1]{{\namefont\textcolor{color0}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\titlestyle}[1]{{\titlefont\textcolor{color2!60}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\addressstyle}[1]{{\addressfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\quotestyle}[1]{{\quotefont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\sectionstyle}[1]{{\sectionfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionstyle}[1]{{\subsectionfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\hintstyle}[1]{{\hintfont\textcolor{color0}{#1}}}
%
\newlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}
\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{0pt}% dummy value
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputecvlengths%
  \def\socialsdetails{}%
  \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
    \protected@edef\socialsdetails{\socialsdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
  % optional detailed information box
  \newbox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}{%
    \addressfont\color{color2}%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}r@{}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@birthdate}}{}{\makenewline{\@birthdate}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@civilstatus}}{}{\makenewline{\@civilstatus}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity will always be defined but could be empty
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@mobile}}{}{\makenewline\mobilesymbol\@mobile}%
      %\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@phone}}{}{\makenewline\phonesymbol\@phone}%
      %\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@fax}}{}{\makenewline\faxsymbol\@fax}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
      \socialsdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
    \end{tabular}
  }%
  % optional photo (pre-rendering)
  \newbox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
    {}%
    {%
      \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
      \color{color1}%
      \setlength{\fboxrule}{\@photoframewidth}%
      \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
      \framebox{\includegraphics[width=64pt]{whatever}}}}%
  % name and title
  \newlength{\makecvtitledetailswidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitledetailswidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}%
  \newlength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}}%
  \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt}}% check for dummy value (equivalent to \ifdim\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt)
    {\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{\textwidth-\makecvtitledetailswidth-\makecvtitlepicturewidth}}%
    {}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{\makecvtitlenamewidth}%
    \namestyle{\@firstname\ \@familyname}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\titlestyle{\@title}}%
  \end{minipage}%
  \hfill%
  % detailed information
  \llap{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of makecvtitlenamewidth is forced
  % optional photo (rendering)
  \usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}\\[2.5em]%
  % optional quote
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\centering\begin{minipage}    {\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[2.5em]}}%
      \par}% to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after                     \makecvtitle
    \makeatother
    % personal data
    \firstname{Name}
    \familyname{Surname}
    \title{Master of Science}                                                                                                      
    \birthdate{Birthday}
    \civilstatus{XXX}
    \address{Street}{City}{Country}
    \mobile{Mobile}                                                                         
    %\phone{}   
    %\fax{}    
    \email{Mail}                                                                                 
    \social[linkedin]{linkedin}
    %\homepage{}                                                                                           
    %\extrainfo{\linkedinsocialsymbol~poksche}
    \photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}
    \begin{document}
    \makecvtitle
    \section{Education}
    \cventry{Grade}{Course}{University}{2014}{M.Sc.}{}
    \end{document}
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: just looking there's clearly a `%` missing from `        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle oh boy, that was too easy... thank you very much. First problem solved. What about the second point? Do you have an idea about changing the icons for mobile, mail etc.?

Comment: search suggests http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96557/change-icons-associated-with-phone-mobile-and-email-in-moderncv (which i apparently answered:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm not sure if this post will help me out since I'd like to have more modern icons. right now I'm coming up with exactly those icons as in the other post. I've already seen more modern icons such as a smartphone-icon for your mobile number. however, I don't know how to reproduce them. maybe I missed a point in the other post, but it doesn't seem to tackle the problem of the "modernness" of icons, does it?

Comment: ive never used the class but search suggests it has commands to switch icon sets eg: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110342/moderncv-non-marvosym-symbols/110360#110360ests

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks for this link. that's exactly what I'm looking for. unfortunately it's not working though my TeXlive version is the one from 2014 according to the log file. even if I compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX it isn't working (as suggested in your link). any suggestions?

Comment: out of time, there are plenty of people on site with experience of the class, I'll let someone else take over, good luck:-)

Comment: all right, however, thank you very much @DavidCarlisle

Answer (score 2):

As @DavidCarlisle said in his comment the error is a missing `%`.  I added it in the following MWE (see line with `<=============`).

As you can see I was able to compile with XeLaTeX your given MWE with an added `\moderncvicons{awesome}` to use other symbols with no error message or warning. See screenshot below.

MWE:

```
   \RequirePackage[demo]{graphicx}
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}   

\moderncvtheme[black]{banking}



\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\moderncvicons{awesome} %  awesome, marvosym or letters 

\makeatletter


\newcommand*{\birthdate}[1]{\def\@birthdate{#1}}
\newcommand*{\civilstatus}[1]{\def\@civilstatus{#1}}

\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{34}{36}\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\titlefont}{\LARGE\mdseries\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\addressfont}{\small\mdseries\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\quotefont}{\large\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\sectionfont}{\Large\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionfont}{\large\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\hintfont}{}

% styles
\renewcommand*{\namestyle}[1]{{\namefont\textcolor{color0}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\titlestyle}[1]{{\titlefont\textcolor{color2!60}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\addressstyle}[1]{{\addressfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\quotestyle}[1]{{\quotefont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\sectionstyle}[1]{{\sectionfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionstyle}[1]{{\subsectionfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\hintstyle}[1]{{\hintfont\textcolor{color0}{#1}}}
%
\newlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}
\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{0pt}% dummy value
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputecvlengths%
  \def\socialsdetails{}%
  \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
    \protected@edef\socialsdetails{\socialsdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
  % optional detailed information box
  \newbox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}{%
    \addressfont\color{color2}%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}r@{}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@birthdate}}{}{\makenewline{\@birthdate}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@civilstatus}}{}{\makenewline{\@civilstatus}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}%  %<===============================
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity will always be defined but could be empty
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@mobile}}{}{\makenewline\mobilesymbol\@mobile}%
      %\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@phone}}{}{\makenewline\phonesymbol\@phone}%
      %\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@fax}}{}{\makenewline\faxsymbol\@fax}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
      \socialsdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
    \end{tabular}
  }%
  % optional photo (pre-rendering)
  \newbox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
    {}%
    {%
      \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
      \color{color1}%
      \setlength{\fboxrule}{\@photoframewidth}%
      \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
      \framebox{\includegraphics[width=64pt]{whatever}}}}%
  % name and title
  \newlength{\makecvtitledetailswidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitledetailswidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}%
  \newlength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}}%
  \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt}}% check for dummy value (equivalent to \ifdim\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt)
    {\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{\textwidth-\makecvtitledetailswidth-\makecvtitlepicturewidth}}%
    {}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{\makecvtitlenamewidth}%
    \namestyle{\@firstname\ \@familyname}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\titlestyle{\@title}}%
  \end{minipage}%
  \hfill%
  % detailed information
  \llap{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of makecvtitlenamewidth is forced
  % optional photo (rendering)
  \usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}\\[2.5em]%
  % optional quote
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\centering\begin{minipage}    {\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[2.5em]}}%
      \par}% to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after                     \makecvtitle
    \makeatother
    % personal data
    \firstname{Name}
    \familyname{Surname}
    \title{Master of Science}                                                                                                      
    \birthdate{Birthday}
    \civilstatus{XXX}
    \address{Street}{City}{Country}
    \mobile{Mobile}                                                                         
    %\phone{}   
    %\fax{}    
    \email{Mail}                                                                                 
    \social[linkedin]{linkedin}
    %\homepage{}                                                                                           
    %\extrainfo{\linkedinsocialsymbol~poksche}
    \photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}


\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Education}
\cventry{Grade}{Course}{University}{2014}{M.Sc.}{}
\end{document}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

If you can't compile my MWE without errors you have a problem with your system.  Then it is important to know the error messages from the log file.  But I think the better place to discuss this problem is the other question ...